# Convert serial printing to pdf

Tags: pdf, printing

I have a lab measurement instrument that upon completing measurement, outputs the result as to a printer. The connection to printer is through an old fashion serial 25 pin port, which most modern printer does not have any longer. The supported driver from the measurement instrument is either Epson or IBM.

I have brought an adapter that converts the 25pins serial to usb.

Question:
In stead of printing to a printer, is it possible to print to my laptop? If yes, which software to use?

Thereafter, I will create a pdf of the print.

Comment: There are software which can let you "print to PDF". Install it on your Lab computer. No need to connect it to laptop.

Comment: Can you use this software to capture print from the instrument to the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recommend a single integrated software product to solve your issue, but I can suggest an approach to devising your own solution.

I suggest breaking the problem into two phases:

1. *Capture the output from the printer to a file via a terminal emulator connected to the virtual serial port.* Ultimately, a serial connection just transmits a stream of bytes. A terminal emulator should be able to connect to the virtual serial port offered by the USB adapter, and give you an option to save the received data to a file. You will need to do some research to find a terminal emulator that will serve your needs.
2. *Use a converter application to convert the printer data to PDF.* Since it's a driver for an Epson printer, the data stream is most likely formatted as ESC/P, which was their common printer language in the days of serial ports (IBM printers used this language too). I expect the file you saved in step one to be a stream of ESC/P commands; you can probably find an application that can convert it to PDF (or perhaps convert it to Postscript, which can be converted to PDF). Off the top of my head, Ghostscript might do the job (but I have not used it in a while).

Ultimately this is old enough hardware that you will have to handcraft a solution. Hope this helps.